# Why do I get an error when running ggplot2 in R 3.5.0?

Tags: r

I am trying to run ggplot2 in R 3.5.0 but it is giving the following error. I can only use this version since it is the only approved at my company.

I have tried removing the package e reinstalling different version but only the ggplot2 version 3.2.0 successfully installed. I tried newer and older versions and it does not install. I am using a Windows computer.

```
library(ggplot2)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")):
>    number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.5.3

Comment: How exactly did you install ggplot2? What versions of all the dependencies do you have installed? I might try just clearing out all packages in your library and reinstalling. Also maybe trying installing from source if you are set up to compile packages yourself.

Comment: I tried to install ggplot2 from source using `install.packages("ggplot2")` but I keep getting a lot of errors that the downloaded packages are not the same length: `Warning in install.packages : downloaded length 4096 != reported length 66186`. So I downloaded all the depedent packages, one by one, and installed them before installing ggplot2. The installed versions were: ‘stringi 1.4.3’, ‘colorspace 1.4’, ‘plyr 1.8.4’, ‘stringr 1.4.0’, ‘labeling 0.3’, ‘munsell 0.5.0’, ‘RColorBrewer 1.1’, ‘gtable 0.3.0’, ‘lazyeval 0.2.2’, ‘reshape2 1.4.3’, ‘scales 1.0.0’, ‘viridisLite 0.3.0’, ‘withr 2.1.2’

Comment: Finally got it to work after installing and removing, I think it was a connection problem and mirror availability. Thanks!